# R: Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : invalid first argument in a 20 iteration code that seems to occur for no apparent reason?

Tags: r, igraph, tidyverse

Although I looked at other posts that talked about similar errors however they did not align with my current issue.

I am currently running a simulation which contains a code like this:

```
    g <- add_edges(g, c(sample(V(g)[V(g)$d == 1], 1), sample(V(g)[V(g)$a == 0], 1)))
```

However, whenever I run this code I always encounter a problem. I always receive an error that states:

```
 Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : invalid first argument
```

and likely because of the first error my dataframe does not contain any values What am I doing wrong in this code because I am sure that I have not used sample.int at any point in this code? I am assuming the problem stems from this code because this is the only point that I use the code sample() and removing it causes the errors to stop as well.

Comment: This is far more info than necessary. Have you identified *where* the error occurs by stepping through the code line-by-line and case-by-case? If not, I'd start there. You'll probably find that nobody is going to be bothered debugging a large script on your behalf.

Comment: I have identified the error to a line of code that occurs 3 times throughout the entire code and runs once per iteration and changed my initial post accordingly.

Comment: At a guess, I think the problem is in one of the `sample()` calls, where it dispatches to `sample.int`. Since you have an 'invalid first argument' error, i'd suggest taking a look at the results of `V(g)[V(g)$d == 1]` and `V(g)[V(g)$a == 0]` and seeing if either one of those returns nothing. I.e., I can replicate the error by doing `sample(integer(0),10)`

Comment: They both return their respective nodes.

Comment: I believe that the cause of this error in my case had something to do with the package "tidyverse". Once I removed it the error stopped appearing.

Comment: `tidyverse` is a meta-package that imports a lot of stuff, so it could be hard to pinpoint if there is an issue there. I suspect it may not be the culprit here, but without actually having your data it's tough to make a firm conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I ran through your code which was available in the older version of you post here:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47522942/revisions

It would run past the line sometimes and sometimes not. What I saw was that there is a non-zero probablity that the value:

```
V(g)$d == 1
```

returns an entirely FALSE array. That means that the value

```
V(g)[V(g)$d == 1]
```

Will be an empty `igraph.vs` object, which generates the error.  Looking more closely at everything:

```
V(g)[TRUE]
+ 30/30 vertices, from b785c8d:
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
[24] 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

In the above case we would have 30 values to sample from whereas, if we subset on an entirely `FALSE` array we would have no values to sample from:

```
V(g)[FALSE]
+ 0/30 vertices, from b785c8d:
```

Moreover, the lengths of these `igraphs.vs` objects are 30 and 0 repsectively.

```
length(V(g)[TRUE])
30

length(V(g)[FALSE])
0
```

So why the `sample.int` error?

Looking at the source code of `sample` we can see that given an array like object `x`,  `sample` will just return a subset of the array where the subset is taken by doing a `sample.int` on `length(x)`:

```
 x[sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob)]
```

To see where the error you get comes from, we just have to see what happens if we try to do `sample.int(0, 1)`:

```
Error in sample.int(0, 1) : invalid first argument
```

So to solve your issue, you would need to ensure that you don't sometimes have an object with length 0, or to have someting handling what to do when this is the case.